# Bug with CASE statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I have the following piece of code:

```
            IF i.cd_ver IS NULL OR i.cd_ver = '0'
            THEN
--Set value of v_cd_ver
                v_cd_ver := CASE i.cd_ver
                                WHEN NULL
                                THEN '9'
                                WHEN '0'
                                THEN '10'
                            END;
            END if;
```

"i" is the record found in the cursor referenced to an external table. The value is NULL or blank in the external table:

```
SELECT cd_ver FROM table_xtl WHERE cd_id = '123';
```

..This returned one row blank.

HOWEVER, `v_cd_ver` did not get set to `'9'` as expected. My work-around was to use `IF THEN` statements instead and it works. Why is the `CASE` statement not working as expected??

UPDATE:
When I tried instead the following it worked:

```
        v_cd_ver := CASE 
                        WHEN i.cd_ver IS NULL
                        THEN '9'
                        WHEN i.cd_ver = '0'
                        THEN '10'
                    END;
```

Is this a bug or there's some reason why the former did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case i.cd_ver when NULL ...` is logically equivalent to `case when i.cd_ver = NULL ...` You know full well that such a comparison results in UNKNOWN, not in TRUE, so the `case` expression falls through to the default value, which is `NULL`. (To test this for yourself, add `else 'x'` before `end` and run it again, you'll see.)

The right way to write it is `case when i.cd_ver is null then '9' when i.cd_ver = '0' then '10' end`.

Answer (score 3):

That form of ['simple' case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) compares the value - `i.cd_ver` here - with each of the comparison expressions, looking for one that is equal.

> In a simple CASE expression, Oracle Database searches for the first WHEN ... THEN pair for which *expr* is equal to *comparison_expr* and returns *return_expr* ...

The important bit there is "for which *expr* **is equal to** ...". Since [nothing is ever equal to null, even itself](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm), there is no match.

To look for nulls you would need a searched case exprssion instead:

```
            v_cd_ver := CASE
                            WHEN i.cd_ver IS NULL THEN '9'
                            WHEN i.cd_ver = '0' THEN '10'
                        END;
```

Not related, but are you sure 0, 9 and 10 should really be treated as strings?

Comment: Yes strings. Is there any difference in using CASE vs. IF THEN in this specific case? Performance?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, case is more compact but you'd be doing the same logical comparisons and evaluations. I don't think I've ever done a comprehensive test, but it would be fairly simple to compare them if you think there could be a significanti mpact.

Comment: One benefit of CASE expressions is that the code can be more easily "copied over" to SQL code. We don't know how the OP is using this, but it is entirely possible that he doesn't need PL/SQL in the first place; if the code is to be re-written in plain SQL, CASE expressions can be copied and pasted; IF-THEN-ELSIF-THEN-...-END IF will have to be rewritten.

Comment: Sure, but I'd only read/interpreted the comment as being about performance; I missed it was looking for other benefits...

Comment: Fair enough... but the greatest performance improvement may indeed come from rewriting whatever the PL/SQL code does in plain SQL! :-)

Comment: Absolutely *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check empty ('') value or `is NULL`

Comment: @user3224907 - in Oracle '' is the same as NULL. (Not compliant with the SQL Standard... in their defense, the Oracle thing about '' and NULL was introduced before there was a Standard.)